# I receive an error org.apache.hc.core5.http.NoHttpResponseException: 172.19.83.193:2375 failed to respond when i add this to Docker Host URI?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I receive an error org.apache.hc.core5.http.NoHttpResponseException: 172.19.83.193:2375 failed to respond when i add this to Docker Host URI?

even i use the ip given

I tried tcp:172.19.193:2375 and unix-connect:/var/run/docker.sock

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  The error message loosely suggests that something is trying to connect to an unsecured Docker daemon on a remote system, and if this didn't return "connection refused" it'd be a sign of a _huge_ security problem (as in, "trivial remote root exploit").

Comment: Are you trying to connect to docker host from jenkins (as worker)?

Answer (score 0):

Same error with Jenkins 2.438

Despite having configured the uri to `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`, Jenkins persist in trying to connect with uri https://localhost:2375

[image: screenshot]